# Preserve whitespace using the Contains method in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to add items to a list of which's 'text' value contains any of the specified words in a string array. For example:

```
string[] myArray = { " win ", " win." };

Item 1 | Enter to win something!
Item 2 | Windows is better than Mac OS
Item 3 | Winning is great
Item 4 | I hope that I will win some money
```

Out of these items I would want to add only items 1 & 4 to my dynamic list.

Here's my code so far which does return the items I want, but the problem is that it also returns rows of which's value also includes part of that word. E.g. the word 'win' also returns 'window', 'winning' etc.. (I'm fetching the original data from a MySQL db, hence the DataReader)

```
string[] myArray = { " win ", " win." };

if(myArray.Any(reader["text"].ToLower().Contains))
{
    list.Add(new{
        Text = reader["text"].ToString()
    });
}
```

I first thought to add spaces around the items in a string array (and also a '.' incase the word is at the end of a sentence), but something in my code seems to be stripping out/ignoring the spaces.

Is there a solution using my current method, or is there generally a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why would #2 fit your criteria but not #4.?

Comment: I would recommend using `Regex`, instead or the `IndexOf`method as suggested by @PatrickHofman

Comment: Because? @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ

Comment: Regex does the job pretty well. And as far as `IndexOf` goes, I just judged it by your info.. :p

Comment: `IndexOf` is a 100 times faster since it doesn't have to compile anything. In this case, `IndexOf` is just the best option. @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ

Comment: @PatrickHofman yeah sure; go ahead.... :)

Comment: Downvoted because accepted answer does not correspond to the question asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Contains` does more than just checking if a piece of text is contained in the source. It takes the current culture into account.

I suggest to use `IndexOf` (like recommended in the [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)) which does a literal matching of the text:

```
if(myArray.Any(s => reader["text"].ToLower().IndexOf(s) >= 0))
```

Comment: I don't see how culture differences would match `Winning` and `Windows` from the sample data given.

Comment: Indeed, I guess OP means that 1 and 4 should match.

Comment: @mmmoustache , as per the comments above, how does this answer give you the ability to differentiate between "win", "winning", "win.", "windows" and so on? It seems like a step backwards from what you had in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

So by regex escaping your search phrases and combining them with an OR alternation `|`, and surrounding them with the expressions to match either whitespace, (some) punctuation or the start or end of line, you can construct a regular expression that will only match if the search phrases exist with spaces or punctuation around them.

```
var punctuation = @"/\.,:;'""!";
var escapedPunctuation = Regex.Escape(punctuation);
var myArray = new[]{ "win", "fun" };
var searchPatterns = myArray
                       .Select(Regex.Escape);
var alternatedPatterns = string.Join("|", searchPatterns);
var fullRegexPattern = string.Format(@"((^|\s|[{0}]){1}($|\s|[{0}]))", 
                                     escapedPunctuation, 
                                     alternatedPatterns);
// so regex pattern is:
// ((^|\s|[/\\\.,:;'"!])win|fun($|\s|[/\\\.,:;'"!]))

var itemsToSearch = new[]{"Enter to win something!",
                          "Windows is better than Mac OS",
                          "Winning is great",
                          "I hope that I will win some money",
                          "Windows, win, woo",
                          "this is fun!"};

var matches = itemsToSearch.Where(i => Regex.IsMatch(i, fullRegexPattern));
```